# Hide the required sign

Tags: forms

I need to hide the red "required" star sign, but I can't understand how to hide this red star mark using `hook_form_alter()`.
I know this can be done using CSS, but I want to know if it is possible to do it using `hook_form_alter()`, or if there is any other way to hide it programmatically.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: no point to do this unless if it is a autofill. is this is a field or title ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use themename_form_element() to remove asterik as given in the [link](https://drupal.org/node/141790#comment-4141050).

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_form_element($element, $value) {
  $output  = '<div class="form-item"';
  if (!empty($element['#id'])) {
    $output .= ' id="' . $element['#id'] . '-wrapper"';
  }
  $output .= ">\n";

  //REPLACE THIS
  //$required = !empty($element['#required']) ? '<span class="form-required" title="' . t('This field is required.') . '">*</span>' : '';
//WITH THIS


  if (!empty($element['#title'])) {
    $title = $element['#title'];
    if (!empty($element['#id'])) {
      $output .= ' <label for="' . $element['#id'] . '">' . t('!title: !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
    }
    else {
      $output .= ' <label>' . t('!title: !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required)) . "</label>\n";
    }
  }

  $output .= " $value\n";

  if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
    $output .= ' <div class="description">' . $element['#description'] . "</div>\n";
  }

  $output .= "</div>\n";

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `!empty($element['#required']) ? '' : ''`. Why would you check `$element['#required']` if the variable is always set to `''`?

Comment: You can remove `'!required' => $required` from `$output` variable in above code to remove 'required' start sign.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the theme_form_required_maker to change the asterisk to whatever

```
function theme_form_required_marker($variables) {
  // This is also used in the installer, pre-database setup.
  $t = get_t();
  $attributes = array(
    'class' => 'form-required',
    'title' => $t('This field is required.'),
  );
  return '<span' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>*</span>';
  }
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_required_marker/7